# Как выровнять текст по вертикали и горизонтали на bootstrap4?

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap4

Есть блок `conteiner` в нем `row`, а в нем текст. Этот  текст по заданию должен быть посередине блока. И должен быть всегда посередине при изменении экрана. Как мне сделать это?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12"><h1>Привет!</h1></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: приведите пример кода, уточните какая у вас версия bootstrap

Comment: Версия bootstrap4. <div class="container">  <div class="row"><div class="col-lg-12"><h1>Привет!</h1></div></div></div> Простой код. Я просто хочу понять как можно сделать так что бы он центрировался налюбом экране

Answer (score 3):

Учитесь пользоваться поиском на сайте [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/). Пример можно посмотреть [тут](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/text/#text-alignment).

Вариант 1:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <p class="text-center">Текст по центру</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Вариант 2. Выравнивание и по вертикали (подробнее [тут](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/)):

```css
.d-flex{
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col my">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <p class="text-center">Текст по центру</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! Вы меня спасли от мучений! Та да . Стоит покапаться в документации.

Comment: @DimaKononov  Если мой ответ вам помог и решил вашу проблему, пожалуйста, примите его.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте класс `text-center` [Документация](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/text/#text-alignment)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h1>Привет!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: нет нет...НЕправильно поняли меня. Текст должен быть  по центру горизонтали и по вертикали.